# PostgreSQL integer thousands separator

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes I need to generate large amount of synthetic test data, like several millions of rows.

Normally, when I expect there to be, say, ten millions rows in a table, I write queries like the one below to generate this synthetic data

```sql
SELECT generate_series(1, regexp_replace('10 000 000', ' ', '', 'g')::INTEGER) AS id;
```

But I am bothered by this useless regex function call and explicit integer conversion.
Is there any default thousands separator in postgres dialect? Like underscores in Java and C# (10_000_000) so I could write the query above this way:

```
SELECT generate_series(1, 10_000_000) AS id;
```

Or maybe there is another solution to making the code more understandable than this separator?

Comment: You forgot to tell us where that weird number format comes from. Perhaps you could fix it there?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, maybe I haven't made that clear, that's just some order of magnitude I expect to be in some table. It is written by hands with no other input source. I'll clarify it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use the underscore separator in numeric constants since Postgres v16.

Reference:

[Official docs: Lexical Structure > 4.1.2.6. Numeric Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC)

[Underscores in numeric constants in PostgreSQL 16](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/underscores-in-numeric-constants-in-postgresql-16/)

Answer (score 4):

Could you use scentific notation, like this

```
select generate_series(1, 1e10)
```

It would meet your ergonomic needs as long as you don't need to specify the exact end of the series

Comment: That's just perfect, thanks! It completely fits my needs, but I hesistate marking it as the correct answer, as it does not the answer the actual question. Still, I will use this solution in future. Thanks! :D

Comment: Well, no new answers are here, and I'm still using your solution, so probably it should be accepted as the correct answer. :D